# Selenium Driver.Quit() not working when passed by reference

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not sure whether this issue is caused by the fact that I am passing the driver by reference. When the browser takes too long to load or loads forever I want to quit it and then create another instance of the driver and browser. I pass the driver by reference like this;

```
...
ScrapeCase(ref caseLookUpDriver, lastCase);
...
```

And my `ScrapeCase` method looks like this;

```
private void ScrapeCase(ref ChromeDriver driver, SQLiteDb.Case lastCase)
{
    for (int attempts = 0; attempts < 3; attempts++)
    {
        try
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(lastCase.CaseType.SummariesURL);
            ...
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (driver != null) { driver.Quit(); }
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        }
    }
}
```

With this code the driver or browser is never destroyed and instead what I get is a new browser window opening over and over each time an exception occurs.

The idea is tell the method `ScrapeCase` which driver to use and I figure I can do this with pass by reference.

Comment: what is the error exception you are getting. Also try `driver.quit()` followed by `driver.close()`

Comment: I agree with the question about the error exception, but I would definitely not recommend calling `driver.Close()` after `driver.Quit()`, as there is nothing to close after calling `Quit()`. `Close()` should almost never be used, unless you are intentionally just closing one window but you intend to still use a different one.

Comment: The problem is when I call `driver.Quit();` Nothing happens. But instead another window is opened by this; `driver = new ChromeDriver(options);` The exception has to do with the timeout since the browser gets stuck and loads forever.

Comment: To me, it looks like you don't want to be passing by reference the way you are using it. As of right now I can't really think of a scenario where you would want to pass the driver as a reference ever. This could be causing some of your problems with quiting the driver.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I see what you're trying to do by passing it as a reference. Out of curiosity though, would it work if you didn't pass by reference, and instead returned the driver you end up with?

Comment: I have created 3 drivers; caseLookUpDriver, Driver2, and Driver3. I want to be able to the method `private void ScrapeCase(ref ChromeDriver driver, SQLiteDb.Case lastCase)` to let it know which browser to use when scraping an item. That's the general idea behind this.

Comment: ...when it fails I can just force that specific driver or browser to quit and then restart.

Comment: @mrfreester No, I just want to tell `ScrapeCase` which driver to use. I don't think returning it will help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163073/discussion-between-mrfreester-and-user5500750).